# Prevent WebView from scrolling to top of page after HTML is added

Tags: java, javascript, android, android-webview

I am writing an Android app that uses a WebView to display content. The main purpose of the app is to display text for a user to read.

I am dynamically adding HTML to my WebView via JavaScript. When adding content to the bottom of the page it is not a problem. when adding content to the top, the WebView automatically scrolls to the top. That's my problem.

**I need to try and find a way to prevent my WebView from automatically scrolling to the top of the page when content is added to the top.**

I do have some limitations though:

1) I am using JavaScript, but am unable to use jQuery.

2) I am currently confined to Android API 8 (v2.2).

3) I don't want to just scroll back to my original position.
*(I have found many solutions on SO for this issue in which I would just programatically scroll back to my position before the scroll. I have a current implementation of this, but it is not a smooth enough transition.)*

4) I need to allow the user to continuously scroll upward while content is being added. *(While I am open to an implementation of disabling scrolling to prevent the WebView from scrolling itself back up, I need to allow the user to keep scrolling up while I am adding content a screen's height or so above them.)*

Sorry if this seems confining, but you can see why I needed some advice.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around my problem. If anyone has another, especially a more direct, answer I would still be interested.

I was, in part, mis-diagnosing my problem. When I add HTML using:  `document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, topDiv.nextSibling);`, I add my new HTML just below the top edge of the document.

I thought I was scrolling back up to the top of the screen (co-ordinates [0,0]), but instead the document length was changing and my current Y position stayed the same. So the co-ordinates I was viewing were constant, but the HTML those co-ordinates displayed changed. The effect was "scrolling up" the page.

I ended up adding a HUGE div of white space above my visible text. Every time I add HTML it shrinks by the exact height of the added HTML. This offsets the added text, allowing my visible screen to stay the exact same. This means **NO** scrolling, which is a ***much*** more fluid UI.

This gives a whole different set things to work around, like stopping the user from scrolling the whole length of my white space and ensuring I don't make my WebView larger than my max size. The trade-offs are well worth it though, as the user experience is drastically improved.